# Unable to add files to Subversion on mapped drive

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a server, containing all of our intranet files, mapped to my computer.  The files are already backed up by the parent organization, but I play hell getting them back if there is a crash...the word "timely" isn't part of their normal vocabulary.  I already have a code repository for development software and would like to add the intranet files to it.

However, when I go to my mapped drive to add them, TortoiseSVN does not give me the option to export these files to the repository.

Am I doing something I'm not supposed to (putting files from a mapped drive into subversion), or is there some setting I need to change to enable this?

Comment: there is an issue with SVN1.9(.1) on old SMB1 shares which will be fixed with 1.9.2

Comment: have you tried TSVN 1.9.2?